# Is there a way to fix this code spreading a reference to an object into a new object?

Tags: rust

If I run the below Rust code I get the below error, why?

Please note that the `let first: &Option<Box<Player>> = &Some(Box::new(Player {` part is what I'm getting from an internal function, the code I need to change starts at `let mut _new_one = Player::default();`:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct OtherBigStruct {
    pub big_field: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Player {
    pub name: Option<String>,
    pub other_big_struct: Box<OtherBigStruct>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let first: &Option<Box<Player>> = &Some(Box::new(Player {
        name: Some("Bob".to_string()),
        other_big_struct: Box::new(OtherBigStruct {
            big_field: Some("field".to_string()),
        }),
    }));

    let mut _new_one = Player::default();

    if 1 == 1 {
        // some condition
        if let Some(first_player) = first {
            _new_one = Player { ..**first_player }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ceeaeb2af7b3032b131491bec429440)

the error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `first_player.name` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:26:24
   |
26 |             _new_one = Player { ..**first_player }
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `first_player.name` has type `Option<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `first_player.other_big_struct` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:26:24
   |
26 |             _new_one = Player { ..**first_player }
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `first_player.other_big_struct` has type `Box<OtherBigStruct>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 2 previous errors
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you want to `.clone()` the value, no? The struct update syntax consumes fields from the `..value` but you can't do that with a reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Move value out of `first`:

```rust
    let first: Option<Box<Player>> = Some(Box::new(Player {
        name: Some("Bob".to_string()),
        other_big_struct: Box::new(OtherBigStruct {
            big_field: Some("field".to_string()),
        }),
    }));

    let mut _new_one = Player::default();

    if 1 == 1 {
        // some condition
        if let Some(first_player) = first {
            _new_one = Player { ..*first_player }
        }
    }
```

**Option 2**

Use Arc instead of String to make copying cheaper.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Default, Clone)]
struct OtherBigStruct {
    pub big_field: Option<Arc<str>>,
}

#[derive(Default, Clone)]
struct Player {
    pub name: Option<String>,
    pub other_big_struct: Box<OtherBigStruct>,
}

fn main() {
    let first: &Option<Box<Player>> = &Some(Box::new(Player {
        name: Some("Bob".to_string()),
        other_big_struct: Box::new(OtherBigStruct {
            big_field: Some("field".to_string().into()),
        }),
    }));

    let mut _new_one = Player::default();

    if 1 == 1 {
        // some condition
        if let Some(first_player) = first {
            _new_one = Player {
                name: first_player.name.clone(),
                other_big_struct: first_player.other_big_struct.clone(),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP said they cannot do that as they get the object from some function they don't control.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Well, the OP is unlucky then, it is impossible to do what he wants in such case.